# What is the missing command to carry the cell title from UITableView to new ViewController via this segue?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have `ViewController` that contains a `UITableView`.  Data is loaded into that table via the following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UsernameSentDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var receiveUsername: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var userEmailText: UILabel!
var userEmail: String?

var communities = [String]() { didSet { communitiesTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
var flag = false

@IBOutlet weak var communitiesTableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func unwindToHome(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

}

//recieves email address from delegate from LoginViewController
func userLoggedIn(data: String) {

  userEmailText.text = data
     }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.communitiesTableView.delegate = self
    self.communitiesTableView.dataSource = self

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.communities.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let title = self.communities[indexPath.row]

    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    cell.textLabel?.text = title

    return cell

}
```

I then set up 1 prototype cell within the `UITableView` so I could create a segue to my second view controller, `ShowCommunitiesViewController` and named this segue, `"showCommunitySegue"`

In `ShowCommunitiesViewController` I have a label set up and ready to use as the title of the cell name carried across, named `communityName`.

In `ViewController` I have set up the following function to deal with the segue, including the destination variable for the cell title that has been selected.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCommunitySegue", sender: self)
showCommunityController.communityName = //what do I put here?
    }
```

What do I need to put on that last line so `showCommunityController.communityName` displays the cell title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare `selectedCellTitle` as `String` in your viewController where your cells are.

```
var selectedCellTitle: String?
```

This will be the global variable keeping track of the selected cell's title.

Add the following in `didSelectRowAt`:

```
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
// Set your global variable to the title
            self.selectedCellTitle = self.communities[indexPath.row]
// Trigger your segue
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCommunitySegue", sender: self)
        }
```

Override `prepareforsegue` method the following way:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "showCommunitySegue" {
// Check if the segue's destination viewcontroller is your viewcontroller
                if let showCommunityController = segue.destination as? ShowCommunityViewController {
// Assign the selected title to communityName
                    showCommunityController.communityName = self.selectedCellTitle
            }
        }
    }
```